# Inject configuration from client to library auto configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, nats.io

I am trying to build a shared platform library (`streaming-client.jar`), which will be used in Spring Boot applications.

That library (`streaming-client.jar`) internally uses a dependency (`nats-spring`), which provides auto configuration,

so whenever it finds some properties in `application.properties` like `serverUrl`, `maxConnection` it will automatically connects to server and does all the configuration server so we can just simply use `@Autowired` to get those connection objects.

This is working as expected in as standalone jar file.

Now, my usecase is that I want to add this lib (`straming-client.jar`) in some spring boot microserivice, and I want, this jar file to read `props` from client microservice `application.properties` and create objects, which should be available by using `@Autowired`

I want to do in two ways

1. If `streaming-client.jar` finds certains props in client `application.properties` it should auto configure and create required objects.
2. Client service should provide some sort of properties object `StreamingProperties.java` a simple POJO with all required properties in it. and inject that to the `streaming-client.jar` context. and it should automatically create objects.

I am stuck on how to approach this.

Your guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: I think you are looking for [custom spring boot starter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-starter)